# make randomiser bookmarklet outputs from selected links

Tags: bookmarklet

I have this bookmarklet:

```
javascript:void(window.open(document.links[Math.floor(Math.random()*document.links.length)].href,'_blank'))
```

It outputs random link from a document full of links.

I want to make it randomisingly output from only some particular links out of many links on a page.
What should I do?

Comment: How will you determine these particular links ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Firefox, to get all links within selected text:

```
var x = document.createElement("div");
x.appendChild(window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).cloneContents());
var links = x.getElementsByTagName('A');
```

Here is a tip for IE: http://pclancey.com/tutorial/selectsrc/

Answer (score 0):

You can select the links that you want to be allowed.

The code will check what text is selected on the page and save it in a variable allowedLinksText. Then the code will check if the innerHTML of each link to see if that innerHTML is included within allowedLinksText.

This will work if each link text is unique. If not, it might let some links be opened that should not be opened. There might be a way to get the HTML code of selected text, but I don't know it.